# Как проверить GET параметр без значения?

Tags: php, get

Всем привет. У меня есть гет-запросы вида:

```
getdata?contact&term=text
getdata?company&term=text
```

Как мне теперь проверить именно гет-запрос, где `contact` или `company`?

`$_GET['company']` вернул пустое значение. Ссылка должна быть именно с `&term=text`.

Код в таком виде:

```
  if(isset($_GET['company']) && isset($_GET['term']))
     {

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, что именно непонятно. У вас уже есть код, который проверяет наличие company в запросе. `isset` делает именно это

```
if(isset($_GET['company']) && isset($_GET['term']))
{

}
```

Если надо просто определить тип запроса, то (при условии что он всегда идет первым)

```
$type = array_key_first($_GET);

// ну и валидацию какую-никакую накинуть
if (!in_array($type, ['company', 'contact'], true)) {
    die('incorrect request');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (Input::has('company') && Input::has('term'))
{

}
```

UPD: Нужно ведь сразу указывать, что фреймворк.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests

Comment: Не работает. Я делаю autocomplete на jquery + laravel.  
Именно не показывает autocomplete.

Comment: @Nelzz, поправил ответ.